# how can i remove second firefox in ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: apt, software-installation, firefox, dpkg, snap

i had firefox snap in ubuntu 21.10. i decided to install firefox apt package and then remove the snap one. so i run `apt install firefox` and it was installed.

but it seems it is another firefox snap package not apt one. so, right now i think i have 2 firefox snap packages and both are version 95! also i can not even distinguish which one is former and wich one is later! i tried to remove last one by running `snap remove firefox` command but after running that both firefoxed still exist.

**my questions are:**

how can i make sure new firefox is apt package or snap one?

how can i remove last snap one (firefox)?

how ubuntu allows this to happen which cause mess in OS?!

Comment: Please add output of `snap list | grep -i firefox`, `flatpak list | grep -i firefox`, `dpkg -l | grep -i firefox` and `which firefox` to the question by editing it.

Comment: Your final point (*Ubuntu allow this to happen*) as I read your question is because the user gave commands to require it. Installing a second packaged version will cause both to exist; you specifically mention the command that would create this condition, but did not provide any clue as to how you removed the prior *snap*.  It was user created because you didn't `snap remove`  (or your description was incomplete; you implied wanting snap removed but never mention removing it; an `apt install` will not remove a snap)

Comment: Ubuntu does not nanny you or question what you tell it to do. If you instruct your system to install two different instances of the same software, it will obey. apt and snap are two different package management systems. Are you sure that the snap was not uninstalled?  You did not tell us anything about the result/output of that command. Did it fail? Did the output indicate that it was successful?  Are you sure the software might be removed but there is still a . desktop shortcut in `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications`?

Answer (score 4):

Snaps and traditional DEB files are independent. Uninstalling one doesn't uninstall the other.

If you need to uninstall the default snap Firefox you can either use the Ubuntu Software tool or use a simple command:

```
sudo snap remove firefox
```

Answer (score -1):

i found th answer for "how can i make sure new firefox is apt package or snap one?"

actualy the answer is so simple. using `firefox >>> menu >>> help >>> about firefox` you will see "mozilla firefox snap for ubuntu" statement.

[image]